# How to align this Table to make all <TD>s correctly aligned

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

How can I align all table rows come correctly aligned even if they have content length differences.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cKj98/) is the fiddle. Please have a look at this.. They are coming vertically aligned.. But I want them one after another  like below

```
One  1  Yes
Two  2
Three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <td width="50px">  
            One  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            1  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            Yes  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td width="50px">  
            Two  
        </td>  
        <td colspan="2">  
            2  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td colspan="3">  
            Three  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
</table>
```

Good ways to style the table cells are: "padding", "text-align", vertical-align", "height", "width", and so on..

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/cKj98/1/

```
vertical-align: top;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you seek

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    One
    </td>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td>
    Yes
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Two
    </td>
    <td colspan='2'>
    2
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='3'>
    Three
    </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```